# Get exact date of next year SQL server

Tags: sql-server, date

I want one sql syntax that give me a date which is passed as parameter. Here is full description :

If I pass 1 as parameter the it should give a date of next year of current date

ex. Current date : 16/02/2016

```
If 1 then 16/02/2017

If 2 then 16/02/2018
```

Please help me to get date as specified.

Thank You.

Comment: [DATEADD](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_dateadd.asp) should do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This maybe:

```
DECLARE @param AS INT
SET @param = 1
SELECT DATEADD(YY, @param, GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are having incoming date in @currentDate and @parameter is somthing you passed then it will work like this, you can use this.

```
 If @parameter=1 Begin Select DATEADD(YEAR,1, @currentDate ) end

 If @parameter=2 Begin Select DATEADD(YEAR, 2, @currentDate) end
```